# Advanced C# pattern search in long string (100-25000 char)

Tags: c#, string, design-patterns

Let me start with this: I can't zip it or anything similar.

What I'm trying to do is search through fairly large strings. I use data blocks that look like `0g12h`. (The `0` is the color from my palette. The `g` is a space to divide the numbers. The `12` means 12 pixels in a row use that color. The `h` is to divide the numbers again.)

The problem I'm having is that the blocks aren't all the same length. They range from `0g1h` to `2546g115h`. Basically I want to create a palette of common patterns to hopefully save space. Say I have: `12g345h19g12h190g11h` occurring at least three times, then I could save space if I had something like: `a=12g345h19g12h190g11h` in the palette array and just put 'a' in the string. Or even not look at the data blocks, as you see in the attached file you get `g640h` a ton of times.

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure this could work. If you have a better idea how I could save space and not lose data, I'm more than open to the ideas.

Here is a great example since you can visually see the pattern: http://pastebin.com/5dbhxZQK. I chose this file because I knew it would have massive redundancy; most aren't this simple.

Comment: For what reason are you using a string for structured data like this?

Comment: Besides UpTheCreek´s comment, why not compressing your data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx ?

Comment: "how i could save space and not lose data"... You could zip it...

Comment: i cant use zip, and the structure was just my natural attempt to shorten the original data. now i see a way to do that more, so i thought id ask for help since i failed at all my attempts

Comment: Are you familiar with Huffman encoding? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: i am familiar with the theory, i dont know how to incorporate it. im still a student so im big on knowing theory, but i dont always know how to translate that to code you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary (probably `Dictionary<string, int>` and just could how many times each pattern occurs, then go back and rewrite the string with the appropriate replacements.

However, I would recommend that you read up a little about compression algorithms, what you are implementing appears to be a Run Length Encoding (RLE) scheme. You are then trying to compress again on top of that, consider looking at how Sliding Window compression works (which is what GZIP does) as an alternative to your RLE. Or look at Huffman encoding as a mechanism to reduce the amount of space needed for the codewords that you are creating (in simple terms Huffman encoding uses shorter symbols for more frequent patterns and longer symbols for less frequent patterns in a 'optimal' way)

This is a fun problem space to play in! Good Luck!

Comment: i tried that, the problem i ran into is: i cant simply compress the files. i need a ruby program to be able to read the strings and when i compressed the with gzip i couldn't get ruby to read them correctly

Comment: Sure, I figured that you were using something like that, I'm assuming that you are taking a constraint (real, or imagined, or for fun, or to learn) that you can't use an off the shelf compression, so you have created your own RLE scheme, and are looking at ways to make it even better (`g640h` is already pretty good compression... if only all images where like that!), Sliding window and Huffman have the challenge that they normally require operating on bitfields, which might be tricky in ruby...

Comment: yes, thats why i moved to c# my original program was 100% ruby but its too slow for the conversion. so i made a c# version to create the files, but ultimately i still need it in my ruby program. since g640h is 640 pixels long i feel good :D

Comment: Many/Most compression algorithms are asymmetric, they take longer to compress than de-compress... while you are compressing, if you track how many times you see each sequence (for example in a `Dictionary<string,int>`), then at the end of the file you can pick the most common sequences and replace them with some special code. Then at the top of the compressed file you just define those codes once, and everytime the decoder sees **a** it knows that means **g640h** or whatever. In a sense, both Sliding Window and Huffman compression do something like this.

Comment: i agree thats what i want to do, im just not sure how, im not asking anyone to write the code for me. but some help with sudo code would be amazing. i guess i shall look up dictionary<string,int> since ive never seen that :) thanks for your help thus far

Comment: Another thing to consider... while the string feels long at 25000 char, that's not a huge amount of memory (as unicode 50K), so you can most likely work with it in memory. In which case I would recommend that you look at the `StringBuilder` class which is great for constructing and manipulating strings.

Comment: i looked up the dictionary thing, i have a pretty good idea of what to do. ill come back and let you know how that goes. thanks for the point in the right direction

Comment: i was able to get it to work, on my 686k file i got it down to 388k, thanks for your help